# ANDEngine : Dynamically Scaling Player Sprite

Tags: android, svg, andengine

Im developing a game in ANDEngine GLES 2.0 .
I intend to scale up and down my player (object) dynamically during the game play based on certain user input.

I have the graphic of the player available in both vector (SVG) and bitmap (PNG) formats. Using BitmapTexture converts the graphic to a bitmap and therefore the object gets distorted when scaled up.

What would be the best possible approach in ANDEngine for achieving this i.e. avoiding upscaling distortion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1:

Make your player texture the largest size, and scale down. Downsampling tends to look better than upsampling.

Option 2:

Render the texture at several resolutions, use the one that is appropriate. An example of this is the effect of the mushroom in classic Super Mario Bros. 16 pixel Mario is swapped out for 32 pixel Mario when he collects the mushroom.

Comment: good example for *option 2* :) @asma.farhat If your sprite's image is of a high resolution then go for *option 1*. To have a smoother scaling effect you may want to use `TextureOptions.BILINEAR` or `TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA`for your `TextureAtas`, this avoids "hard pixels" when scaling.